# Optimize case statement with a single select in PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL script

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm using a select-case statement in order to set a session variable with the value of the logical condition.
This is the statement:

```
select case when exists( select 1 from group_views where cwgv_group=vGroup and cwgv_table=0) then '1' else '0' end,
           case when exists( select 1 from group_views where cwgv_group=vGroup and cwgv_table=1) then '1' else '0' end,
           case when exists( select 1 from group_views where cwgv_group=vGroup and cwgv_table=2) then '1' else '0' end,
           case when exists( select 1 from group_views where cwgv_group=vGroup and cwgv_table=3) then '1' else '0' end,
           case when exists( select 1 from group_views where cwgv_group=vGroup and cwgv_table=4) then '1' else '0' end
    into existCondition0, existCondition1, existCondition2, existCondition3, existCondition4;
```

Next, I put set session variables with those variables:

```
PERFORM session_variable.set('CTX.ENTITY_CONDITION',existCondition0);
PERFORM session_variable.set('CTX.ZONE_CONDITION', existCondition1);
PERFORM session_variable.set('CTX.FUNCTION_CONDITION', existCondition2);
PERFORM session_variable.set('CTX.STORE_CONDITION', existCondition3);
PERFORM session_variable.set('CTX.CONTRACT_CONDITION', existCondition4);
```

I wonder how can I optimize this script, like using just one Select, but nothing comes in my mind. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. Query written using single select statement including CASE. Use MAX/MIN function to handle no data found condition.

```
select COALESCE(MAX(case when cwgv_table = 0 then 1 end), 0)
     , COALESCE(MAX(case when cwgv_table = 1 then 1 end), 0)
     , COALESCE(MAX(case when cwgv_table = 2 then 1 end), 0)
     , COALESCE(MAX(case when cwgv_table = 3 then 1 end), 0)
     , COALESCE(MAX(case when cwgv_table = 4 then 1 end), 0)
into existCondition0, existCondition1, existCondition2
   , existCondition3, existCondition4   
from group_views  
where cwgv_group = vGroup;
```

***Please check this url:*** https://dbfiddle.uk/nppF7JMs

Comment: It works. But it's not quite understandble how MAX function handle NULL value

Comment: if your select query doesn't return any record then variable is empty. MAX function does not handle null values it is used only for single record. Without it multi records will return. COALESCE handle null values. If your query doesn't return record MAX function return NULL values.

Comment: I understand. It's clear now, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to return booleans, not integers, you can use the [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) `bool_or()`:

```
SELECT BOOL_OR(cwgv_table = 0) AS b0
     , BOOL_OR(cwgv_table = 1) AS b1
     , BOOL_OR(cwgv_table = 2) AS b2
     , BOOL_OR(cwgv_table = 3) AS b3
     , BOOL_OR(cwgv_table = 4) AS b4
FROM group_views  
WHERE cwgv_group = 1;
```

This function also handles NULLs, that will result in a `false`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm currently handling those values as 'character varying' and I can't use bool_or(). I'll remember this function!

Comment: In this example bool_or() works on the comparison `cwgv_table = 0`, that results in TRUE, FALSE or NULL and is a boolean. No matter what data type you use in `cwgv_table`.